# Doctrine not in join table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having some hard time solving a really trivial problem.
I need to get all USER entities, that are not present in a join office_user table. I'm using Symfony 3.4 with Docrine.

The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user
LEFT JOIN office_users ON user.id = office_users.userId
WHERE role = 'ROLE_USER' AND office_users.userId is null
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userId FROM office_users)
```

But doesn't work solving this with Docrine.

Here is the Office Entity

```
//AppBundle/Entity/Office
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="office")
 * @JoinTable(name="office_users",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="officeId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $users;
```

The User entity

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Office", mappedBy="users")
 */
 private $office;
```

and the DQuery

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
           ->createQuery(
               'SELECT u FROM AppBundle:USER u LEFT JOIN u.office o WHERE u.role = :role'
           );

$query->setParameters([
    'role' => 'ROLE_USER',
]);

return $query->getResult();
```

But when I dump the User entity I see no element in Office collection, but my mySQL database disagree.

Comment: I guess in dql you need to add `AND o.id IS NULL`

Comment: I had it in there like few moment ago but it throw me some error. Now it magicaly works... thank you

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid please add new answer as it solves the issue. Comments are used for improvment or asking more informations and clarifications. Then Rudolf will validate your answer